# TFS - Find In Files

Tags: tfs, vs-extensibility

My team has just migrated from VSS to TFS 2013.  On VSS, we would often search the entire database for the occurrence of some string (usually a table or procedure name) to find out everywhere it is used.  This functionality is clearly not available in TFS.

I have seen some alternatives, none of which sound very viable in our environment.  As a result, I started tinkering with creating an app (or extension) to do it directly from TFS.  However, the only way I found to do it is to download and search each file one at a time (I also could not find a way to filter the return from GetItems with a list of file extensions), which is slow and undesired.

Is there a faster way, through the API, to search through the source files in a TFS server?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has announced that they are working on this exact feature, and it should be coming to Visual Studio Online in Q1 2015, and to on-premise TFS sometime after that.

You can read about it at the bottom of this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/11/12/news-from-connect.aspx

Also the estimated timeline is publicized here:
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx

[image]

Comment: Excellent news.  Hopefully it will get pushed to TFS2013 as well as VSO and TFS2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TFS Administrators Toolkit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/33713c5d-31a3-44b3-ae94-3c413e6b21c7), here is the description of search feature:

http://mskold.blogspot.se/2012/09/find-in-files-new-feature-of-tfs.html